# web3py ABIFunctionNotFound

Tags: solidity, web3py

I'm new to web3 development, trying to signing transaction over web3py and got an exception ABIFunctionNotFound when I try to create transfer via `contract.functions.transfer()` function for USDC token on BSC network.

```
web3.exceptions.ABIFunctionNotFound: ("The function 'transfer' was not found in this contract's abi. ", 'Are you sure you provided the correct contract abi?')
```

**Token ABI**

`[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"logic","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"admin","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"previousAdmin","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"AdminChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"implementation","type":"address"}],"name":"Upgraded","type":"event"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"changeAdmin","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"implementation","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"}],"name":"upgradeTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newImplementation","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"upgradeToAndCall","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"stateMutability":"payable","type":"receive"}]`

If there are no function transfer in this contact, how can I transfer USDC to another wallet?

Comment: Please edit your question and share the ABI that you're passing to the python Contract instance. My guess is that you're using an incorrect ABI not containing the `transfer()` function. Possibly of the USDC proxy contract - not of the implementation.

Comment: Edited. Please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guessed in the comment, you're passing the ABI of the [proxy contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x8ac76a51cc950d9822d68b83fe1ad97b32cd580d#code).

The solution is simple: Pass the ABI of the [implementation contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0xba5fe23f8a3a24bed3236f05f2fcf35fd0bf0b5c#code) (you can see it linked from the Proxy contract on BSCScan) but keep the proxy address.

This rule applies to all other proxy contracts if you encounter this issue another time. Always pass the proxy address and the implementation ABI.

Comment: could you please explain how did you figure it out? I believe I have the same issue, but on Arbitrum network. I am working with this contract (https://arbiscan.io/address/0xb87a436b93ffe9d75c5cfa7bacfff96430b09868#code) and trying to scan for `ExecuteIncreasePosition` events. I know it's there in the ABI, but I'm getting `web3.exceptions.ABIEventFunctionNotFound` error.

Comment: @ievgenii My guess came from the function names reflected in the ABI JSON - it contains function names such as `implementation` and `upgradeToAndCall` - which suggested an upgradable proxy contract. Docs page: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy

Comment: in looking at the TrueUSD contract, how do I determine the address of the "implementation" contract? https://etherscan.io/token/0x0000000000085d4780B73119b644AE5ecd22b376